# How do I tell if I'm using the GOLD linker?

Tags: gcc

Someone else in my group built LD for my team to use. How can I tell if it was built with --enable-gold?

Answer (score 7):

Check the symlink `/usr/bin/ld` via `ls -al`, if it links to `ld.gold` or `ld.bfd`. The rest should be obvious.

Note: Nameing might be slightly different, the above is true for ArchLinux. On other systems `ld.gold` might be called `gold` directly and `ld.bfd` could be called `ld`.

Comment: The GCC I'm using was built by a coworker, not installed by the system. GCC -v seems to indicate that "--enable-gold" was provided but was looking for something more concrete than that. Does LD give no indication as to which one it is?

Comment: try a `ld -v` and it should tell you what is inside
Either `GNU gold (GNU Binutils 2.23.2) 1.11` or `GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.23.2` should appear

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to comfirm how gcc is configured. So gcc -v will do the trick.